# Amperage for Sony SNC-VB630 Camera

Tags: dc, camera, adapter, amperage

I am trying to choose a right DC adapter for SNC-VB630 CCTV Camera but the only specs I could find in the official documentation was 'INPUT 12V DC'. Nothing about amperage. I have a 12V dc adapter with 400mA current at hand and I was wondering if that would suffice. How can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the correct [camera](https://pro.sony.com/bbsc/assetDownloadController/SNC-VB630%20corrected.pdf?path=Asset%20Hierarchy$Professional$SEL-yf-generic-153711$SEL-yf-generic-153760SNC-VB630%20corrected.pdf&id=StepID$SNC-VB630%20corrected$original&dimension=original) the specs says
Power Requirements
PoE system (IEEE 802.3af compliant), DC 12 V ± 10%, AC 24 V ± 20%
Power Consumption : 6.0 W max

The current I = P / V
Then 500mA max to provide the camera with the power it may need.

Also this [site](http://www.tssgroup.sk/produkty/sony-snc-vb630-boxova-ip-kamera) also states the max, not sure of the language but it does say 500mA max.

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct to state that 400mA might damage the camera? (Insufficient amps)

Comment: It's probably best to just pick up a 500mA power supply off amazon they're fairly cheap, so you can provide the camera with enough power if it may need it.